# ExtJs Pagingtoolbar display error

Tags: extjs

I have some problems with my pagingtoolbar in ExtJS

When the grid and the pagingtoolbar is loaded for the first time, the pagingtoolbar shows "page 1 of 1". After refreh it shows the full page count like "1 of 100"

My Store is defined like this:

```
Ext.define('AM.qat.store.Employee',{
    extend: 'AM.qat.data.Store',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Direct'],
    model: 'AM.qat.model.Employee',

    remoteGroup: true,

    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 25,
    autoSync: true

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({}, config);
        if (!config.proxy) {
            var proxy = {
                type: 'direct',
                reader: {
                    idProperty: 'Id',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    type: 'json',
                },
                writer: {
                    allowSingle: true,
                    writeAllFields: true // Note: Changed in ExtJS 5 to be default false
                },
                api: {
                    read: AM.qat.Employee.List,
                    create: AM.qat.Employee.Create,
                    update: AM.qat.Employee.Update,
                    destroy: AM.qat.Employee.Delete
                }
            };
            config.proxy = proxy;
        }

        this.callParent([config]);
        this.proxy.on('exception', this.onProxyException, this);
    }
});
```

The pagingtoolbar is docked under the grid and uses the same store as the grid

```
    me.dockedItems = [
                {
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    store: me.store,
                    width: 360,
                    displayInfo: true
                }
]
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How does the response from the server look like? In order for the paging toolbar to work properly, the response must include count, offset and total properties.

Comment: Response:

`action: "Employee"
method: "ListJournal"
result: {total: 133,…}
data: [{Id: 57710, Client_id: 1006, Employee_id: 4666, Action: 2, Type: 1, FirstName: "Bastian",…},…]
total: 133
tid: 21
type: "rpc"`

Comment: When i refresh the paging, then its correctly -  but the same response